# Why is my submersible pump circuit dropping pressure?

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

Pump wont shut off. Has new pressure switch. Checked pressure tank and tank pressure  good. Backflow to 0psi within seconds of shutting power off to pump. Pump only gets up to 48psi while continually  running.   Bad check valve cause both issues? Or cracked line? Also when shutting off power to pump I can see the water movement way down at water level inside well casing so I'm sure its backflowing at the bottom.

Comment: A bad check valve should not cause the pump not to get up to pressure, it will not keep the the pressure.

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts. You can request to have them combined so that you can edit your own posts without awaiting a review of the edit, among other things. See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: If you don't see that movement when the pump is running, only when shutting it off, it is more  likely to be check valve (backflow when turned off) than cracked pipe (which would have water recirculating out of it all the time the pump is running, and after it shuts off as it leaks down.)

Answer (score 2):

Pump is worn (or well level has dropped a lot) if it won't make pressure.

Separate issue is check valve is shot if it drops to zero when it shuts off.

You'll need to pull the pump to repair or replace. If that's a problem you could temporarily adjust the pressure switch lower and put in a surface-mount check valve before the pressure tank to limp along until you can get the pump out and repaired or replaced.

**Alternate possibility:** There *may* be a leak in the pipe between the pump and the pressure tank. That would cause both symptoms, but is *normally less likely* than the causes above. You might hear a lot of water noises at the well head when the pump is running if it's a leak in the pipe coming up inside the well. That would be water spraying out of the pipe and falling back down the well. You might find a big wet spot if it's a leak between the well-head and the house underground.

Comment: The pump will have to be pulled. Check the line from the pump to the tank as you pull it out, be sure thee is no leak. If you do not find one cap the ends and add about 100 PSIG compressed air and see if it holds pressure, if not replace it. If it does replace the check valve which is part of the pump in my system.